# 1St value does not select in picker view

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

Hi 
iam having some buttons when click one button picker view apper but does not select the first value if it scroll then only fist value selected so plz help me

here is my code

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {



    switch (tagVlaue) {

    case 0:
    { 
        if(gender==YES)
       {

           NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [checkArray objectAtIndex:row], row);

           selectedgender=[checkArray objectAtIndex:row];
           NSLog(@"selected checkgender %@",selectedgender);
           genderlabel.text=selectedgender;
          // checkgender=NO;
       }
     else 
         {

             NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [genderArray objectAtIndex:row], row);

             selectedgender=[genderArray objectAtIndex:row];
             NSLog(@"selected gender %@",selectedgender);
             genderlabel.text=selectedgender;
            // checkgender=YES; 


        }
        //genderlabel
    }
        break;
    case 1:
    {
        if(gender==NO)
        {
        NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [seekingArray objectAtIndex:row], row);   
        selectedseek=[seekingArray objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog(@"selected seeking %@",selectedseek);
        seeklabel.text=selectedseek;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [seekCheckArray objectAtIndex:row], row); 
            selectedseek=[seekCheckArray objectAtIndex:row];
            NSLog(@"selected seeking %@",selectedseek);
            seeklabel.text=selectedseek;
        }

    }
        break;

    case 2:
        NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [ageArray objectAtIndex:row], row);

        selectedage=[ageArray objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog(@"selected age %@",selectedage);
        label.text=selectedage;


        break;
    case 3:
        NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [feetArray objectAtIndex:row], row);  
        selectedheight=[feetArray objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog(@"selected height %@",selectedheight);
        heightlabel.text=selectedheight;


        break;

    case 4:

        NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [weightArray objectAtIndex:row], row);    
        selectedweight=[weightArray objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog(@"selected weight %@",selectedweight);
        weightlabel.text=selectedweight;

        break;

    case 5:
        NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [enthnicityArray objectAtIndex:row],row);


        selectedethnicity=[enthnicityArray objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog(@"selected weight %@",selectedethnicity);
        ethnicitylabel.text=selectedethnicity;

        break;

    case 6:
        NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [typeArray objectAtIndex:row],row);


        selectedtype=[typeArray objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog(@"selected weight %@",selectedtype);
        typelabel.text=selectedtype;

        break;


    default:
        break;
}
```

thanks for advance

Comment: More information please. Code?

Comment: what is tagVlaue?? may be it's because of this, put NSLog in default case and see the problem...

Answer (score 1):

The delegate method:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

is called only when the user explicitly select the value in the picker. You must get the value that is selected in the picker when the picker is first displayed by yourself. For example you can look at the picker data source.

Comment: your have to save the picker's previously selected value.

Comment: i use this delegate method but does not show 1st value when scroll then first value show

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate method of UIPickerViewDelegate `– pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` to know which row has been selected if nothing is selected by the user this won't be called.

Comment: i use this delegate method but does not show 1st value when scroll then first value show

Comment: - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {NSLog(@"Selected Color: %@. Index of selected color: %i", [ageArray objectAtIndex:row], row);

        selectedage=[ageArray objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog(@"selected age %@",selectedage);
        label.text=selectedage;